# Google Play Downloader Library errors

Tags: android, android-library, expansion-files

When I create a new project from existing source (Google play downloader library) to use with APK expansion files, the project is added with many errors in:

- DownloaderClientMarshaller.java
- DownloaderServiceMarshaller.java
- DownloadProgressInfo.java
- DownloaderService.java
- DownloadNotification.java
- V11CustomNotification.java
- V3CustomNotification.java

The library targetSdkVersion is 15

Adding the library to my project generates the following errors:

```
[2012-04-17 23:03:54 - Atlas] D:\Programming\android sdk\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\play_apk_expansion\downloader_library\res\values-v9\styles.xml:3:     error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name     'android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent'.

[2012-04-17 23:03:54 - Atlas] D:\Programming\android sdk\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\play_apk_expansion\downloader_library\res\values-v9\styles.xml:4:     error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name     'android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete values-v9. It's helped me.