# Notification default text color

Tags: android, notifications, styles

This documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView

Says:

... to apply the system's default colors for notifications on Android 2.3 and higher, use the following styles for `res/values-v9/styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="NotificationText" parent="android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" />
    <style name="NotificationTitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title" />
</resources>
```

I'm using android 1.6 for development.

But if I do the above, then I get this error:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent'.
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Similar question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198653/google-play-downloader-library-errors

Comment: are you using support libraries?

Comment: What's that? My app is working well without this piece of code, and I have android libs on my classpath.